# Does z3's SAT solver obtain a complete assignment before doing a theory consistency check?

Tags: z3, smt

Does z3's SAT solver(s) obtain a complete assignment to the propositional(ized) part of an SMT problem before doing a theory consistency check? In particular, I am curious to know what is done by default for each of the following background theories/combination (if this is theory-dependent): Linear Real Arithmetic (LRA), Linear Integer Real Arithmetic (LIRA), Non-Linear Integer Real Arithmetic (NIRA)? Also, where in the actual code (codeplex stable z3 v4.3.1) is a propositional literal (heuristically) decided by the SAT solver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Z3 does not obtain a complete assignment before doing theory consistency checks.
However, it delays "expensive" checks. "Expensive" checks are performed in a step called `final_check` that is performed only when a (complete) proprositional assignment is produced. Here the word "expensive" is relative. Linear real arithmetic consistency checks can be quite expensive due to big number arithmetic computations, but they are considered "cheap" in Z3.

Linear real arithmetic checks are done eagerly. Nonlinear and linear integer arithmetic checks are done at the `final_check` step.

Note that Z3 contains more than one solver. The behavior above is for the one implemented in the directory `smt`. The nonlinear real arithmetic solver (`nlsat` directory) works in a completely different way, and it does not use the `final_check` approach described above.

Comment: A clarification sought: by eagerly, for linear real arithmetic, did you mean after /*every*/ propositional decision (which I believe leads to an assert_upper() or assert_lower()) ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The method `void theory_arith<Ext>::propagate()` will be invoked before the SAT engine performs a new decision.